# How to resolve circular dependency in DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to set the `TenantId` in my `DbContext` so that I can filter all queries using it.

I have set up the filter, but I am having difficulty getting the `TenantId` to the `DbContext`.

The reason for the difficulty is that the `UserManager` which is used to get the currently logged in user (and thus the `TenantId`) depends on the `DbContext` to get data from the database.  So I cannot import the `UserManager` with Dependency Injection because it results in a circular dependency. The `UserManager` depends on the `DbContext`, and the `DbContext` depends on the `UserManager`.

Is there some other way to configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you have a situation like this:

```
public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    public UserManager(IDBContext db, ... )
    {
        _context = db;
        ...
    }
    private IDBContext _context ;
    public UserInfo User {get; set;}
    // ... Some logic that fills User 
}

public class DBContext : IDBContext
{
    public DBContext(...)
    {
        ...
    }
    // ... Here you need UserInfo to filter.
}
```

Change the structure of you application a little, and make it like this:

```
public class UserProvider : IUserProvider
{
    public UserInfo User {get; set;}
}

public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    public UserManager(IDBContext db, IUserProvider provider, ... )
    {
        _context = db;
        _userProvider = provider;
        ...
    }
    private IDBContext _context ;
    private IUserProvider _userProvider;

    // ... Some logic that fills _userProvider.UserInfo 
}

public class DBContext
{
    public DBContext(IUserProvider provider, ...)
    {
        _userProvider = provider;
        ...
    }
    private IUserProvider _userProvider;
    // ... Here you can use _userProvider.UserInfo
}
```

Only requirement: Register IUserProvider as a singleton in your Dependancy Injection Framework